# Mysql get data smaller than and if equal smaller than other field

Tags: mysql

these are my data in mysql table. 
I want to get data having city_code<12 and 
city_code=12 entrytime<3500

```
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
| CityCode | entrytime |      newsheader       |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|       11 |      3800 | great opening         |
|       10 |      3700 | flood alert           |
|       12 |      3600 | new mall              |
|       13 |      3500 | pollution at the city |
|       13 |      3400 | new mayor             |
|       12 |      3300 | house fire            |
|       11 |      3200 | traffic accident      |
|       10 |      3000 | Festival at city      |
+----------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

This is my sql code

```
SELECT * FROM  `entries` WHERE (`CityCode ` <  '12') 
OR (`CityCode` =  '12' AND entrytime<  '3500')
```

this code gives me only the rocrds smaller than 12. 
how can i get smaller and (if equal) smaller than other field values? 
Thanks

Comment: '3500' is a string (so is '12'). perhaps you want 3500

Comment: It works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6f6d8/2

Comment: That can't be the actual query you ran, because you have an extra space after `CityCode` on the first line.

Comment: Works fine for me too: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/376ff/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/376ff/2) (after removing the extra space in the `CityCode` column name.  (I'm assuming that was a typo, and that you don't actually have two columns, one named "`CityCode`" (without a trailing space) and another named "`CityCode `" (with a trailing space.)

Comment: I see it works fine. Query is logically true. But my mysql server only gives citycode<12 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine after you remove the whitespace on the first line from 'CityCode'. Remember to watch those extra whitespaces.

```
SELECT * FROM  `entries` WHERE (`CityCode` <  '12') 
OR (`CityCode` =  '12' AND entrytime<  '3500')
```

Comment: and command at the second line must be OR. 
I removed whitespaces and mysql still gives only citycode<12

Comment: good catch my friend I was dinking around with 'and' and 'or' and copied the wrong one!